# How can I focus on google custom search engine field with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search, input

I have tried to grab the element via getElementById method, but - as expected- it did not work.

Comment: Please share with some code that recreates that issue. Its hard to tell what is wrong without seeing your code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `gsc-input:focus{};`, In most cases `gsc-input` is the class added to google custom search.

Comment: You did not get me. I meant I need to set it to focus() when the page loads (using js) , not to do a specific style when I focus it (using css).

Comment: What you are gonna do while focussed in?

Comment: I shall add style to the input field while it is on focus. And I can introduce a search query using javascript after a sepcific timeOut.